# Merging large data.tables on character columns causes segfault

Tags: r, merge, cygwin, data.table

I'm using R version 3.3.3 (though I've replicated this problem on 3.4.0) and `data.table` version 1.10.4 on Cygwin. (**Edit**: comments below suggest that this may be specific to Cygwin.) I need to merge two data tables (about 1 megabyte and 2000 rows) by an alphanumeric ID column. About three times out of four, I get a segfault on the merge call itself or on a later call modifying or printing the merged table. (I understand this as a consequence of lazy evaluation.)

This is a problem with character columns in particular; merging on integer columns works fine. See this terminal session:

```
> library(data.table)
data.table 1.10.4 #[snipping rest of startup message]
> n <- 2e6 # Make this higher if you can't trigger a segfault yourself.
> a <- data.table(a=1:n, b=runif(n), c=runif(n))
> b <- data.table(a=1:n, x=runif(n), y=runif(n))
> head(merge(a, b)) # This works fine.
   a         b          c         x          y
1: 1 0.6753597 0.08822928 0.7204507 0.71065772
2: 2 0.1898733 0.11883707 0.9820610 0.74329076
3: 3 0.3941039 0.57053921 0.3346781 0.22707652
4: 4 0.4564642 0.77429123 0.4924871 0.07743992
5: 5 0.9109421 0.79464586 0.2588091 0.82185820
6: 6 0.1805926 0.94213717 0.7426924 0.52522687
> a <- data.table(a=as.character(1:n), b=runif(n), c=runif(n))
> b <- data.table(a=as.character(1:n), x=runif(n), y=runif(n))
> head(merge(a, b))

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0xffffffffffffffff, cause 'unknown'

Traceback:
 1: `[.data.table`(x, i, , )
 2: x[i, , ]
 3: head.data.table(merge(a, b))
 4: head(merge(a, b))
```

If `a` and `b` are `data.frame`s, then `merge()` doesn't segfault on character columns. Questions:

1. Is this documented or otherwise well-known behavior?
2. Is there a workaround short of making a new ID column or casting back and forth to `data.frame` whenever I need to use `merge()`?

Comment: I wasn't able to replicate this issue, even when setting n to be much larger than your value. Also, I don't think calling `merge()` is going to default to data.table. I loaded data.table and it still looks like it defaults to the base version. Does it still happen if you run `data.table::merge()`?

Comment: @Kristofersen maybe it's a Cygwin issue? And when I try specifying `data.table::merge()`, I get `Error: 'merge' is not an exported object from 'namespace:data.table'`.

Comment: hmmm I'm getting that too. I thought data.table had its own merge function... Maybe I'm confused. You could try something like `a[b, on = 'a']` though to merge. I might be sending you on a wild goose chase, but trying to figure out if it's a base issue or not.

Comment: Huh, `a[b, on='a']` works for me.

Comment: I wonder if it's an issue with base. I'm using R version 3.2.3.

Comment: Which platform?

Comment: I ran it on windows.

Comment: You should try `methods("merge")` and then `data.table:::merge.data.table`. And I can't reproduce this. And why are you using Cygwin in order to run R?

Comment: @DavidArenburg I'm on a computer with Cygwin installed and no admin rights.

Comment: Perhaps [Portable R](https://sourceforge.net/projects/rportable/files/) would be an alternative to a cygwin-compiled R? I don't know why the latter would fail like this, but you may need to determine if it is a problem with your dev environment.

Comment: Can you report this on this issues page? Maybe there's a way to add tests for Cygwin. https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues