# data.table::fread silently corrupts long integers

Tags: r, floating-point, data.table

I'm working with a CSV file with twelve-digit ID numbers, too long to fit into 32-bit integers. When I read them into `data.table`s without specifying column classes, these numbers become very small floats. Here's a sample one-column CSV file:

```
A
540045001186
540123000977
```

And here's the result of `fread`, which gives no warning messages:

```
               A
1: 2.668177e-312
2: 2.668562e-312
```

I think the CSV entries are being read as 64-bit integers but then misinterpreted as binary representations of 64-bit floats. My evidence is that this C program prints `8 8 2.668177e-312` (and if I change `long int i` in the union definition to `int i` or `unsigned int i`, the floating-point number changes):

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef union {
  long int i;
  double f;
} union_t;

int main(void) {
  union_t u;
  u.i = 540045001186; /* first entry in the CSV file */
  printf("%d %d %e\n", sizeof(long int), sizeof(double), u.f);
  return 0;
}
```

Reading the bits of an integer as a floating point seems like a very strange default coercion, and I'm even more surprised that I didn't get any warning. Is this a bug? Here's the output of `sessionInfo()`. Note that I'm running the Cygwin precompiled package, which has caused me bugs that others couldn't reproduce on other platforms ([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44187906/merging-large-data-tables-on-character-columns-causes-segfault)).

```
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-cygwin (64-bit)
Running under: CYGWIN_NT-6.1 INT-3A02 2.8.1(0.312/5/3) 2017-07-03 14:11 x86_64 Cygwin

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /usr/lib/R/modules/lapack.dll

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.10.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.0
```

Comment: This seems like it should be a bug report to the package authors: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues . Not sure what type of answers you are looking for here.

Comment: According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45016068/3817004) you need to `install.packages("bit64")`.