# fread() reads big number as 4.076092e-309

Tags: r, data.table, fread

The original numbers are integers from `825010211307012` to `825010304926185`. `fread()` turns all those numbers to `4.076092e-309`.

`read.table` works normally, but I need to read large data so I can't use it.

How can I correct this error?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44973544/data-tablefread-silently-corrupts-long-integers

Comment: Note that the Github issue is here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2250

Comment: @Scarabee IMHO, https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2250 isn't relevant here as it deals with larger integers > 2^63 which can't be handled by the `bit 64` package.See also https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1618 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32339636/long-numbers-as-a-character-string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you install the `bit64` package then `fread` will use it to read these large integers:

before:

```
> fread("./bignums.txt")
              V1
1: 4.076092e-309
2: 4.076092e-309
```

Do the magic:

```
> install.packages("bit64")
```

Then:

```
> fread("./bignums.txt")
                V1
1: 825010211307012
2: 825010304926185
```

`fread` has read them into 64 bit integers:

```
> fread("./bignums.txt")$V1
integer64
[1] 825010211307012 825010304926185
```

I don't know why `fread` misreads them when `bit64` isn't available. I'd at least expect a warning...

Comment: According to https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md, this has been fixed in the development version 1.10.5: _When fread() and print() see integer64 columns are present but package bit64 is not installed, the warning is now displayed as intended._