# How to get unique() to work on data.tables with character columns?

Tags: r, cygwin, data.table

If I create an R data.table with string columns without calling `stringsAsFactors=TRUE` and then try to take unique rows of the data table with `unique`, then the strings get stripped from the resulting table, though they are considered in determining which rows are unique.

```
> dt <- data.table(x=c('a', 'a', 'b', 'c'), y=c(1, 1, 2, 2), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> unique(dt)
   x y
1:   1
2:   2
3:   2
> dt <- data.table(x=c('a', 'a', 'b', 'c'), y=c(1, 1, 2, 2), stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
> unique(dt)
   x y
1: a 1
2: b 2
3: c 2
```

Is this correct behavior? I'm on Cygwin and have uncovered a few mysterious Cygwin-specific issues in the R internals before. Here's the readout of `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-cygwin (64-bit)
Running under: CYGWIN_NT-6.1 INT-3A02 2.8.1(0.312/5/3) 2017-07-03 14:11 x86_64 Cygwin

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /usr/lib/R/modules/lapack.dll

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.10.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] bit_1.1-12     compiler_3.4.0 bit64_0.9-7
```

Comment: On my machine (Ubuntu 16.04 with `R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30) -- "Single Candle"`) it is working also using the first option.

Comment: I'm not surprised; I've had Cygwin-only problems with R strings before (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44187906/merging-large-data-tables-on-character-columns-causes-segfault).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `duplicated()` function may provide a workaround. `dt[!duplicated(dt), ]` returns the same results as `unique(dt)` for both cases on my system (Ubuntu linux, R version 3.13.0-121-generic)

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(x=factor(c('a', 'a', 'b', 'c')), y=c(1, 1, 2, 2))
all.equal(unique(dt), dt[!duplicated(dt), ])
[1] TRUE
>

dt <- data.table(x=c('a', 'a', 'b', 'c'), y=c(1, 1, 2, 2))
all.equal(unique(dt), dt[!duplicated(dt), ])
[1] TRUE
>
```

Related post: [Finding ALL duplicate rows, including "elements with smaller subscripts"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854433/)

Comment: I don't know why this should work, but it does. Thanks!